# How to run a PDO/ODBC/PHP query with double quote in it?

Tags: php, pdo, escaping, odbc, quote

When I run the following simple query inside Microsoft Access:

```
select * from movie where moviename like 'batman'
```

it works.

Also using double quotes around the string works:

```
select * from movie where moviename like "batman"
```

I have a website where the user can type in *any* select query which PHP will then run and returning the record results to the user. I use PDO/ODBC to connect to the Access database. If the user types in query 1 it works, but query 2 fails with:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)

The documentation says about quote() function:

> "Not all PDO drivers implement this method (notably PDO_ODBC). Consider using prepared statements instead."

but I can't use prepared statement as I don't know what query the user will type in. Sometimes they use '...' around a string and sometimes "...".

To reproduce you only need an Access (.mdb/.accdb) database with at least one table called 'film' and a column 'titel'. Put some records in it. At least 1 with 'Batman'. Use the following testscript:

```
//also using a older Access version of the database "film.mdb" didn't work
//be sure to use full/absolute pathname
$dbnameFile="C:\\wamp\\www\\elearning2\\databases\\film.accdb";
$username="";
$password="";
$accessdriver="{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}";
$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$accessdriver;Dbq=$dbnameFile", $username, $password, 
                array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

//Testcases, comment all but one
//Testcase 1: works
$sql="select * from film where titel like 'Batman'";

//Testcase 2: works
$sql='select * from film where titel like \'Batman\'';

//Testcase 3: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
$sql="select * from film where titel like \"Batman\"";

//Testcase 4: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
$sql='select * from film where titel like "Batman"';

//Testcase 5: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'titel like \[Batman\] 
$sql='select * from film where titel like \"Batman\"';

//Testcase 6: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'titel like []Batman[]
$sql='select * from film where titel like ""Batman""';

$result=$dbDB->query($sql);
$rows=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$result->closeCursor();

foreach($rows as $row) {
  echo $row["TITEL"]."\n";
  echo "<br>";
}

$dbDB=null;
```

How can I properly escape a user given SQL query for PHP/PDO/ODBC/Access? Or is it just not possible to use a "..." string delimiter, despite working in Access?

I also find the error messages for testcase 5 and 6 odd. It looks like the double quote is changed into a `[` or `]`??

I can't use bind parameters, prepared statements or rewrite the query because the query is totally unknown and given by the user and can also contain syntax error(s). I can't modify this user query and just want it to be executed by PDO/ODBC but how?

I use Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12 running locally on a Windows 7 SP1 machine.

I posted an official [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69736)

Here's proof that query 1 and 2 both work in Access:
[image]

Comment: Why is the user responsible to supply quotes around the search term? And why don't you just strip them and then use `quote()` or parameter binding?

Comment: It's a teaching website just like codeschool where my students need to answer a question given a certain database by using an SQL query. I can't use quote() see my question. Also parameter binding is not applicable given the fact the student supplies me with a query.  Also to make the matter more complicated a simple search " and replace with ' will not work for example when the student gives me a query with a single and/or double quote inside a searchstring.

Comment: So if users are entering raw queries, then they're also responsible for properly quoting strings or using the right JetEngine SQL syntax. There's no magic syntax fixing function → short of writing your own to accomodate for any random user input woes.

Comment: You're right about user responsibility and the website won't fix their incorrect queries. I want to just run their query against the database just like a tool like phpmyadmin will. Why would you explain that query 2 works in Access and doesn't in PHP? Forget the user given query.... lets make the question more simple: Is there a way to make query 2 work in my code example?

Comment: Double quotes aren't really standard SQL. Might or might not work in Access (which also isn't), or your ODBC driver transforming them even. PDO however just passes the raw query along. No way to tell. (Btw, a crude regex to separate any string after `LIKE` out from the query then patching it back / parameterizing together might still be an option. Only for those trivial query structures obviously.)

Comment: If you are teaching standard SQL you will have to catch queries with double quotes and message the user that they are not allowed. If it is teaching Access which allows these you will need to modify the query by enclosing the double quotes in single ones.